# Is there a way to trace garbe collector activity in PHP?

Tags: php, garbage-collection, benchmarking

I would like to know if there is a way with PHP5.3 to trace the garbage collector activity like in Java with `-verbose:gc` command line.

I try to know how often and when the collections occurs.

I'm also interesting about the time spent doing the collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can activate [Garbage Collector benchmarking](http://www.php.net/features.gc.performance-considerations.php), recompiling PHP with the `DGC_BENCH=1` flag. You'll obtain statistics like these:

```
GC Statistics
-------------
Runs:               110
Collected:          2072204
Root buffer length: 0
Root buffer peak:   10000

      Possible            Remove from  Marked
        Root    Buffered     buffer     grey
      --------  --------  -----------  ------
ZVAL   7175487   1491291    1241690   3611871
ZOBJ  28506264   1527980     677581   1025731
```

It's not a real trace, but that's the only thing I could find.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although it's not really a trace it's still good informations for me!